# How can I change my "Breaking News" region in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, my default region is The Americas, but my Breaking News on the login screen always seems to be for the Europe region.

How can I change the Breaking News region back to The Americas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had the EU version installed.  I believe this might have been because I prefer to have versions of software that use the Queens English, rather than US English.

Now that I have installed using the online installer and have selected English (US), I am now getting Breaking News for The Americas, rather than Europe.

Answer (score 0):

You might be in a different region. You will probably need to change you region setting in Options > Accounts. Take note if you do this you will not be able to access your EU character on the Americas region (characters are region specific).

Comment: Most of my characters are in the Americas region, and I have one character in the EU region (for when the Americas region is down for maintenance).  However, no matter which region I'm set to, within the game, it always displays the EU Breaking News.

Comment: @Reuben Did you logout and back in after changing your region?